# Inner Join está retornando resultados repetidos

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Possuo três tabelas! Sendo uma delas uma tabela de relação!

São elas:

Pessoa:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tratamento:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela de Relação entre Pessoa e Tratamento:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ao passar o ID da pessoa, a consulta retornasse os NOMES dos tratamentos selecionados.
Exemplo:
ID 8, ele retornaria Reiki e Astrologia; ID 9, ele retornaria Reiki, Astrologia e Coaching Desenvolvimento Pessoal!

O que está acontecendo na minha consulta:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei fazer a consulta colocando `Distinct`, mas não está dando certo! É como se ele estivesse retornando dois resultados(o que eu espero são dois resultados mesmo) só que está vindo todos os outros tratamentos também.

Meu trecho de código:

```
Select * FROM tratamento INNER JOIN pessoa_tratamento_r ON 8 = pessoa_tratamento_r.ID_PESSOA
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda! E por favor, se quiserem colocar links ou outras indicações para estudo, façam isso! **Se há outras maneiras também de fazer esta pesquisa, por favor, digam!**

Comment: `select t.nome from tratamento t inner join pessoa_tratamento pt on pt.id_tratamento = t.id_tratamento  and pt.id_pessoa = 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou relacionar as chaves das tabelas (FK da pessoa_tratamento com a PK da tratamento) no JOIN, conforme o @Rovann comentou ficaria assim:

```
select t.nome 
from tratamento t 
     inner join pessoa_tratamento pt on pt.id_tratamento = t.id_tratamento 
where pt.id_pessoa = 8
```